# How to retrieve data from Firebase realtime database in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new here. I am not able to retrieve data from Firebase database. I want to retrieve name and `food_items` of each category.

**MyDatabase**

```
{
    "categories" : {
        "category1" : {
          "name" : "Babyfood"
        },
        "category2" : {
          "name" : "Dairy"
        },
        "category3" : {
          "food_items" : {
            "item1" : true,
            "item2" : true
          },
          "name" : "Fruits"
        }
      },
      "food_items" : {
        "item1" : {
          "category" : "category3",
          "name" : "Apple"
        },
        "item2" : {
          "category" : "category3",
          "name" : "Banana"
        }
    }
}
```

**FoodCategory.java**

```
public class FoodCategory implements Serializable{

    String name;
    FoodItem food_items;

    public FoodCategory(){}

    public FoodCategory(String name,  FoodItem food_items) {
        this.name = name;
        this.food_items = food_items;
    }

    public FoodItem getFoodItems() {
        return food_items;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public FoodCategory(FoodCategory category){
        this.name = category.getName();
        this.food_items = category.getFoodItems();
    }

}
```

**FoodItem.java**

```
public class FoodItem {
    String name;

    public FoodItem( FoodItem foodItem) {
        this.name = foodItem.getName();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here is my code for retrieving data of each category

```
mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mCategoryRef = mRootRef.child("categories");
    mCategoryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        ArrayList<FoodCategory> values = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                FoodCategory c = snapshot.getValue(FoodCategory.class);
                Log.d("Categories: ", c.name + " " + c.food_items);
                values.add(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

It returns right value for category's name, but null for `food_items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `FoodCategory` model, you mention that it has only **SINGLE** value of `FoodItem`:

```
public class FoodCategory implements Serializable{
    String name;
    FoodItem food_items;
    ...
}
```

And by looking at your database structure, it should be a list/array of `FoodItem` right? And if your `FoodItem` only contains name string as key and boolean true as value (its always true, right?) then maybe you should make it `HashMap`, like this

```
public class FoodCategory implements Serializable{
    String name;
    HashMap<String, Boolean> food_items;
    ...
}
```

That way, you don't need the `FoodItem` custom object. (or you can still use that and make `food_items` a list/array of `FoodItem` custom object.

**EDIT**

Looks like original poster magically "know" what to do and answer it himself (huh?). But for those who have the same problem and looking for answer here, this explanation is for you.

The database structure:

```
{
    "categories" : {
        "category1" : {
          "name" : "Babyfood"
        },
        "category2" : {
          "name" : "Dairy"
        },
        "category3" : {
          "food_items" : {
            "item1" : true,
            "item2" : true
          },
          "name" : "Fruits"
        }
      },
      "food_items" : {
        "item1" : {
          "category" : "category3",
          "name" : "Apple"
        },
        "item2" : {
          "category" : "category3",
          "name" : "Banana"
        }
    }
}
```

In the code sample that posted in question, it reads value on `categories` and search for `categories/???/food_items` for value. Please note that `food_items` I mention here is the ones inside the `categories` not `food_items` parent of `item1` and `item2`.

So of course it will contain `null` for the first and third child as it has, in fact, no value. But the second one will have 2 values:

```
{ "item1":true, "item2":true }
```

> Note: it has 2 values, so I recommend using `HashMap` to read it, because original poster read it as single value.

From there, we know what is wrong. Then after that, you probably want to get detail of `item1` and `item2` because it only contains boolean (it is like a foreign key in sql). Then you should read value `food_items/???` and there you go.

Comment: Each category contains the name of category and List of food items. For example, category3 contains "Fruits" as the name of the category and list of food items are{ Apple, banana} (i.e. Item1, Item2 from food_items). foodItems of food_categories are FoodItems objects. I used  **HashMap<String, Boolean> food_items** but ,still I am getting food_items as null.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was helpful. Can you tell me how to access nested key like category1(it can be any random key) and I don't know, why my constructor is not instantiated using this code **snapshot.getValue(FoodCategory.class)**. I had to initialize it with new operator.

Comment: You have to know what key you want to get, even when it is random. Then do it like this `mRootRef.child("categories/category1")`. Take a look at [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-database/9242/reading-data/28681/understanding-which-data-referenced-by-getreference#t=201702282214462701557)

Answer (score 0):

For iterating all children of a node use ChildEventListener instead.
Don't get confused by the method name 'onChildAdded' , it will go trough all entries the first time.

```
    mCategoryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            FoodCategory c = dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodCategory.class);
            Log.d("Categories: ", c.name + " " + c.food_items);
            values.add(c);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Source : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: food_items still null.

Comment: Your data model is different. The food_item in category 3 has array of booleans , but in your FoodItem model you defined String name. Change either to make it work.