# How to retrieve data from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving firebase database and want to display data on web page like category , description etc.How can i get that thing work?I want to display value next to text like category , description .

**JS**

```
var myParam = location.search.split('itemKey=')[1];
firebase.database().ref('/Sell_Products/' + myParam).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    var name = snapshot.child('name').val();
    alert(name);
    var image = snapshot.child('image').val();
    var category = snapshot.child('category').val();
    var description = snapshot.child('description').val();
    var price = snapshot.child('price').val();
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref("auction/");
    databaseRef.set({
        Image: image,
        category: category,
        description: description,
        price: price,
        uid: user
    });
    document.querySelector('#image').src = image;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="image1">
    <div id="box">
        <img id="image" />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="content">
        <p id="category">Category: </p>
        </br>
        <p id="name">Name:</p>
        </br>
        <p id="price">Price:</p>
        </br>
        <p id="decription">Description:</p>
        </br>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="btn">
    <button class="button">BID</button>
</div>
```

[My web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLsSC.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from Firebase realtime database in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487574/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

In your html add:

```
<p id="category">Category: <span id="categorytext">sample text</span> </p>
```

Then in the js file:

```
 firebase.database().ref('/Sell_Products/'+myParam).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
{var name=snapshot.child('name').val();
 alert(name);
 var image=snapshot.child('image').val();
 var category=snapshot.child('category').val();
 var description=snapshot.child('description').val();
 var price=snapshot.child('price').val();
 document.getElementById("categorytext").innerHTML = category;

});
```

Comment: I worked on your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't worked out.Any other way of doing it?

Comment: I have made use of <input type="textarea"> where i want to show value which i am retrieving but nothing is getting showed up there.I have given id for each text area and in script tag i am writing  document.getElementById("categorytext").innerHTML = category; categorytext is the id of the text area

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21711717/7015400 @AbhishekKumar

Comment: Yes i have recorded my upvotes. @Peter Haddad can you please see this question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49638806/7633292 please.Thanks

Comment: regarding the link, the answer there is correct, it checks if the user is logged in or not